# Difference between watch and $watch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Just a simple question.

What is the difference between options and instance methods?

Based on the watch example, we can implement watcher as an option (https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#watch) and a method of an instance (https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#watch).

From my point of understanding, I can implement exactly the same feature with both methods and the only differences would be the syntax and the place of implementation.

If I am mistaken, can somebody explain to me based on example the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed (almost) correct with your assumption.

There is 2 major advantage of `this.$watch()` though.

1. You can start watching dynamically
2. the return-value of `this.$watch()` is an unwatch function with which you can dynamically stop the watcher during runtime

But that doesn't necessarly mean that you should always use `this.$watch()` over `watch: {}`. The opposite. You should always think about what your use case needs

Unwatch-example:

```js
export default {
//..
created(props) {
  const unwatchAge = this.$watch(() => this.user.age, (value, oldValue) => {
    if (value >= 18) {
      alert('You are now allowed to drive a car!');
      unwatchAge(); //we don't need age watching for anything else
    }
  });
}
//...

}
```

---

BTW with VUE3 you might wanna look into the [`watch() / watchEffect()` composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#setup) methods.

`watch()` does the same as `watch: {}` and `this.$watch()`  and also has an unwatch-method as return-value.

`watchEffect()` checks any value mentioned inside parameter (function) and puts a watcher on it internally.

`watch()` Example (composition)

```js
import { toRef, watch} from 'vue';

export default {
//...
setup(props) {
  const age = toRef(props.age);
  const unwatchAge = watch(age, console.log); 
  // no () => age or () => age.value needed as age is a reference by using toRef and references can be handles like this

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.warn('unwatching age!');
    unwatchAge();
  }, 5000);
}
//...

}
```

`watchEffect()` Example (composition)

```js
import { toRef, watchEffect} from 'vue';

export default {
//...
setup(props) {
  const age = toRef(props.age);
  
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (age.value >= 18) {
      alert('You are now allowed to drive a car!');
    }
  });
  //vue will internally recognize that age has to be watched here. No telling it manually.
}
//...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference from the docs it is that the `instance method` returns a `unwatchable` that you can trigger to stop watching a certain property:

```
const unwatchUsers = this.$watch('users', () => {});

setTimeout(unwatchUsers, 1000);
```

This is not possible with `options` API. It is extremely useful to use this `unwatch` returned by `this.$watch` when something happens in your app.

Have in mind what is the most appropriate to your use case and use it accordingly